# Kafka Streams can not recover in case of Exception while processing Messages

Tags: java, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am playing with Kafka Streams and faced a situation which seems a little odd to me. I did search on this but could not find a proper answer.
While processing the elements in the stream, if any unhandled exception occurs, following error happens and Kafka Streams can not recover, stops processing further messages then I need to restart my application.

```
2018-05-17 11:00:51.304  INFO 43810 --- [-StreamThread-3] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [snapshot-stream-application-a1dbc5d4-1742-4af2-9919-d4f5f861bb36-StreamThread-3] Stream thread shutdown complete
2018-05-17 11:00:51.304  WARN 43810 --- [-StreamThread-3] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [snapshot-stream-application-a1dbc5d4-1742-4af2-9919-d4f5f861bb36-StreamThread-3] Unexpected state transition from RUNNING to DEAD.
2018-05-17 11:00:51.305 ERROR 43810 --- [-StreamThread-3] c.u.kafkastreams.config.SnapshotStream   : Error while processing:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: task [0_4] Failed to flush state store KTABLE-SOURCE-STATE-STORE-0000000000
```

For sure catching all the exceptions will solve the problem, but I am looking for a proper exception handling mechanism for Kafka Streams.
Here is my sample code:

```
  private KafkaStreams streams;

    @PostConstruct
    public void runStreams() {
        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        KTable<String, String> snapshotTable = builder.table(kafkaProperties.getInputTopic());
        snapshotTable.toStream().foreach((key, value) -> {
            process(value);
        });

        streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, consumerProps());
        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();
        streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error while processing:", e);
            }
        });
    }

    private void process(String message) {
        simulateException(message);
        LOGGER.info("Key: {} Value: {}", key, value);
    }

    private void simulateException(String message) {
        if (message.contains("abc")) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void closeStream() {
        streams.close();
    }

    private Properties consumerProps() {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "stream-application");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrap());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 3);
        return config;
    }
```

(I did try with `kafka-streams 0.11.0.0` and `1.1.0`)

Comment: Your code should never throw an exception... Otherwise Streams dies. That's by design. Catching all exception is a proper design.